# Guest account on LineageOS 14.1

Tags: lineageos, 7.1-nougat

I have a Samsung Galaxy S2 (i9100) smartphone with LineageOS 14.1 (2017-02-22 nightly) which is based on Android 7.1.1 (Nougat).

I'd like to enable the guest account feature, but I can't find anything in  Settings. How can I do that?

Please notice my device is encrypted. Are guest accounts compatible with encryption?

See also [this thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/LineageOS/comments/67qgnl/guest_account_with_samsung_galaxy_s2_i9100/) on Reddit.

Answer (score 0):

Slide down status bar to quick access screen and you will see a blue icon in the top right side. press on it and click add guest.

[image: example]

Comment: I don't have any blue icon there...

Comment: i have edited the post

Comment: Nothing, I don't have that blue icon. According to the Reddit thread the LineageOS developer responsible for the Samsung Galaxy S2 chose to disable the guest feature for some reasons...

Comment: ah, unlucky you. sorry i couldn't help.